# Lose milliseconds on DateToISO8601

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

A lot of APIs want the ISO8601 without the milliseconds like this:

> Get only orders which were placed after this timestamp. Should be in YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ format

I guess the main "issue" is the dot after the seconds (between seconds and milliseconds), one would have to url-encode the dot (http GET speaking), right?

```
SDateFormat: string = 'yyyy''-''mm''-''dd''T''hh'':''nn'':''ss''.''zzz''Z'''; { Do not localize }
```

I am unable to lose the milliseconds.

```
DateToISO8601(TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(RecodeMilliSecond(now, 0), false), true)
```

This is my approach at the moment:

```
var
  utc: TDateTime;
...
  utc := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(now);
  utc := RecodeMilliSecond(utc, 0);
  ... Format('/orders?storefront=de&ts_created_from_iso=%sT%sZ', [FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', utc), FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', utc)])
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: You mention "URL Encoding the dot" but this is not a character that needs URL encoding ... which suggests you may be thinking about this in a different way which is not obvious to a reader of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to know how to make `DateToISO8601()` not output milliseconds, correct? The answer is, you can't. But, it would be very easy to strip off the milliseconds after the fact using `System.Delete()` or `TStringHelper.Remove()` since you know the exact offset and length of the milliseconds in the resulting string.

```
var
  utc: TDateTime;
  iso: string;
... 
  utc := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  iso := DateToISO8601(utc, true);
  Delete(iso, 20, 4);
  ... '/orders?storefront=de&ts_created_from_iso=' + iso;
```

Otherwise, just stick with your manually approach. However, you don't need `RecodeMilliseconds()`, and only 1 call to `FormatDateTime()` will suffice:

```
const
  cISOFormat: string = 'yyyy''-''mm''-''dd''T''hh'':''nn'':''ss''Z''';
var
  utc: TDateTime;
...
  utc := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  ... '/orders?storefront=de&ts_created_from_iso=' + FormatDateTime(cISOFormat, utc);
```

Comment: RecodeMilliseconds() was a try to lose the milliseconds. I thought maybe it "goes away" if there is no "real" value to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a routine we use:

```
  function DateTimeToXML(dtInput: TDateTime): String;
  var
    fmt: TFormatSettings;
  begin
    // If this will be used in a multithreaded environment then
    // you should use your own TFormatSettings to be thread safe
    fmt:=TFormatSettings.Create();      // initialize, it's on the stack so MUST NOT be freed
    DateTimeToString(Result, 'yyyy-mm-dd''T''hh:nn:ss''Z''',
                     TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(dtInput), fmt);
  end;
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `TFormatSettings` if you treat the `-` and `:` characters as quoted literals instead of format placeholders, that way nothing in your formatting will be locale-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy the function DateToISO8601 from System.DateUtils and change it to:

```
function [MyClassName].DateToISO8601(const ADate: TDateTime; AInputIsUTC: Boolean = true): string;
const
  SDateFormat: string = '%.4d-%.2d-%.2dT%.2d:%.2d:%.2dZ'; { Do not localize }
  SOffsetFormat: string = '%s%s%.02d:%.02d'; { Do not localize }
  Neg: array[Boolean] of string = ('+', '-'); { Do not localize }
var
  y, mo, d, h, mi, se, ms: Word;
  Bias: Integer;
  TimeZone: TTimeZone;
begin
  DecodeDate(ADate, y, mo, d);
  DecodeTime(ADate, h, mi, se, ms);
  Result := Format(SDateFormat, [y, mo, d, h, mi, se]);
  if not AInputIsUTC then
  begin
    TimeZone := TTimeZone.Local;
    Bias := Trunc(TimeZone.GetUTCOffset(ADate).Negate.TotalMinutes);
    if Bias <> 0 then
    begin
      // Remove the Z, in order to add the UTC_Offset to the string.
      SetLength(Result, Result.Length - 1);
      Result := Format(SOffsetFormat, [Result, Neg[Bias > 0], Abs(Bias) div 
MinsPerHour,
        Abs(Bias) mod MinsPerHour]);
    end
  end;
end;
```